# Why is my shutdown command executed immediately sometimes and delayed in some other cases?

Tags: shutdown, manjaro

I don't know if this is something configured by default on my system (I just recently installed Manjaro i3). I'm just confused that sometimes when I run `shutdown` in the command line, it is executed immediately, but on some other occasions, it is delayed by about 1 minute, and can be canceled via `shutdown -c`.

Is it determined by something like the uptime of the system (i.e. if I have barely turned on the computer before I try `shutdown`, it executes immediately, while if I already have the computer running for a while before I try `shutdown`, it is delayed so that I may save my work etc.). If so, where might I find and change this configuration?

Comment: it's most likely just waiting for some service to shut down, and that service ignores the shutdown signal, so it hangs until the service manager times out and kills it forcefully. Looking at the logs for when this happens should give you an idea what's going on.

Comment: @Patrick I think that's indeed the reason. Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to find which services are causing the issue until the timeout actually happens?

Comment: Hi, what is your shutdown command provided by? Is it systemd or sysvinit? What is the version number of the corresponding package?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you didn't pass a `TIME` argument to shutdown.

> "now" is an alias for "+0",
>   i.e. for triggering an immediate shutdown. If no time argument is
>   specified, "+1" is implied.

-- from `man shutdown` on a systemd system.  Though I would vaguely guess this is interoperable with historical practice, not some arbitrary choice by systemd.

Comment: Interesting. The manual indeed says that "+1" is implied. But what confuses me is that sometimes it shuts down immediately while on other occasions it indeed waits for 1 minute. I'm not sure why. I'll try `shutdown now` in the future and see how it goes.